# Excel timespan calculation for time report

Tags: excel, ms-office

I need to write a time report for my company.

Sadly I have to use a given format:

```
B1: 9.00 - 18.00 //timespan between arrival and leaving

C1: 60.00 //minutes I spent in drinking coffee

D1: 8.00 // total hours of work
```

I need a formula that a) calculates the total hours between the both times in A1, subtracts the minutes of having a break in minutes, and gives me the total hours worked in D1. I am not allowed to change the format of the cells (like writing arrival and departure times seperatly in columns) which makes it complicated.

Thank you in advance, Harry

#### UPDATE

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B16)," ",(TIMEVALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(B16, SEARCH("-",B16,1)-1)))-TIMEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(B16, SEARCH("-",B16,1))))) * 24 -C16/60)
```

Works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that for the result in D1:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(B1, SEARCH(" - ",B1,1)))-TRIM(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" - ",B1,1)-1))-C1/60
```

or if you don't have any spaces between the hyphen (-) I suggest:

```
TRIM(RIGHT(B1, SEARCH("-",B1,1)-1))-TRIM(LEFT(B1,SEARCH("-",B1,1)-1))-C1/60
```

**Explanation:**

`=TRIM(RIGHT(B1, SEARCH(" - ",B1,1)-1))` = right part of the timespan (18.00)

`=TRIM(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" - ",B1,1)-1))` = left part of the timespan (9.00)

`C1/60` = minute of having a break (1 hour = 60 minutes)

Comment: actually I am getting a #NAME error, but I'm on it :) Thanks so far.
I will report when its working

Comment: The formula doesn't work if the start time is double figures - 10.00 etc.

Comment: I just edited my answer try with the new values. Just replace SEARCH("-",B1,1) by SEARCH(" - ",B1,1)

Comment: Replaced english terms with the ones of my language and added some things. Now its working like a charme - Thank you! P.S. there was a -1 missing, I will add my Version  to question text.